# CSS Before Position Fixed

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a very simple modal in CSS and wanted to use a single DOM element for the 'vignette' and the main  content. Thus far I have:

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 620px;
  margin: 0 -320px;
  height: 540px;
  background: $white;
  z-index: 4000;
}

/* Vignette */
.modal:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: $black;
    z-index: 2000
}
```

Unfortunately this is leading to the vignette being displayed over top of the modal (not behind it as desired). How can it be forced underneath without creating a new div for it?

Comment: what about 2 different divs? I don't think "before" applies in this case. Like "modal-bg" e "modal"

Comment: @NDLombardi Thanks. I know it can be done with two divs but I was curious if it could also be done with a single div. Partly because I plan on stacking them. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the top part of the question and the number of reputation...

Comment: @NDLombardi No worries. It looks like I'll have to use two divs regardless. Thanks for the input.

Comment: What does `background: $white;` mean?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Those are SASS or LESS CSS compiler variables. See : http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Did you try negative z-index?

Comment: @MilchePatern, Odd.  So this is some kind of future-proofing in case the definitions of "black" and "white" change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this, at least not with cross-browser code. Pseudo-elements as :before and :after are on another stack started from the parent element.

This is stated in the CSS specification files:

> The :before and :after pseudo-elements elements interact with other
>   boxes, such as run-in boxes, as if they were real elements inserted
>   just inside their associated element

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content

Comment: But they still can be moved down below the *content* of the parent element with negative z-index (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#stack-level). They just can't be placed below the background and borders of the parent element... but this can be worked around.

Comment: try ```content: " ";```

Answer (score 6):

there's one trick you could use to blakken all page from one single element:

```
.modal {
/* your css */
outline: solid 800px black;
}
```

or

```
.modal {
/* your css */
box-shadow: 0 0 0 800px black;
}
```

so it doesnt stand underneath, but all around.

Comment: translucide color might be less 'surprising' for the visitor, so he still knows he didn't leave page, but just opened a modale/dialogue box.

Answer (score 5):

It's about so called [stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#stack-level). Each positioned element establishes the stacking context for its positioned descendants, so such descendants with positive z-index appear above their parent, regardless z-index of the parent itself.

To move the descendant below the parent, you can use negative z-index (e.g. z-index: -1). But even with negative z-index, the positioned child can't be moved below the background of the parent element (kind of counter-intuitive part of standard, but so it works). That's why you will need *two* pseudo-elements — one for the vignette and one for the background for the modal itself.

Example: http://jsbin.com/ajarey/5/edit